# How to exclude a directory from FilesMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess directive:

```
<FilesMatch ".(htm|html|php)$">
  php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/abc/public_html/_prepend.php"
  php_value auto_append_file "/home/abc/public_html/_append.php"
</FilesMatch>
```

I need to exclude a very specific directory '/home/abc/public_html/exclude/` from the auto_prepend and auto_append.

Is it possible?

Comment: FilesMatch matches file names and extensions of the curruent dir. You can not use it to match against directories.

Comment: Ok thanks @starkeen

Comment: Your welcome. If you need to exclude the dir, there is a diffrent way to do this : create an htaccess file in that directory with just the following line **RewriteEngine on**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[.htaccess files - What they are/How to use them](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#what) explains how `.htaccess` files work

> A file, containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a particular document directory, and the directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof.

This means, you can create a .htaccess file in `/home/abc/public_html/`, and another one in `/home/abc/public_html/exclude/` containing the same, different, or even contradicting directives.

---

Looking at [PHP - `auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file), you can see that

> The special value `none` disables auto-prepending.

The same applies to `auto_append_file`.

---

Putting these two things together means, you can have the existing .htaccess

```
# /home/abc/public_html/.htaccess
<FilesMatch ".(htm|html|php)$">
  php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/abc/public_html/_prepend.php"
  php_value auto_append_file "/home/abc/public_html/_append.php"
</FilesMatch>
```

and a second .htaccess in the `exclude` subdirectory

```
# /home/abc/public_html/exclude/.htaccess
<FilesMatch ".(htm|html|php)$">
  php_value auto_prepend_file none
  php_value auto_append_file none
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: ++ for the detailed explaination.