# .htaccess - FilesMatch except a file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have hosted on my server multiple WordPress websites.

I have the `wp-login.php` password protected. I use this code

```
ErrorDocument 401 "Unauthorized Access"
ErrorDocument 403 "Forbidden"
<FilesMatch "wp-login.php">
AuthName "Authorized Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/.wpadmin
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

My question: Is it a way to except a site from this rule?

IE: `/directory/wp-login.php`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well the FilesMatch directive applies to the current directory. So if you want to protect certain folders, then you have to add the FilesMatch directive only to the folders which need to be protected. See [How to exclude a directory from FilesMatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640403/how-to-exclude-a-directory-from-filesmatch) and https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch